# Method call on null when using shared preference

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-provider

I want to use shared preference to keep user login and I'm using API with provider.
I tried to put it in main but I don't how to do it because I have two different page to go so it was used in the first page but I found another error

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception:
> NoSuchMethodError: The method 'login' was called on null. E/flutter (
> 4199): Receiver: null

and this is the method which I used

```
UserProvider userProvider;
  ServiceProvider serviceProvider;
  bool alive = true;
  bool isLoading = false;
  var page;

  @override
  initState() {
    init();
    super.initState();
  }

  init() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool language = prefs.getBool('language');
    bool type = prefs.getBool('type');
    bool login = prefs.getBool('islog');
    if (alive) {
      if (language == true && type == true && login == true) {
        signIn();
      } else if ((language == true && type == false && login == true)) {
        visitor();
      }
    } else {
      if (alive) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  signIn() async {
    //var res = await userProvider.residentLogin(context, phone, pass);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var phone = prefs.getString('phone');
    String pass = prefs.getString("pass");
    bool type = prefs.getBool('type');
      print("Shared ***************resident********************************");
      await userProvider.residentLogin(context, phone, pass);
      await serviceProvider.getHomeServiceList(context);
      await serviceProvider.getAdsList(context);
      await serviceProvider.getVideosList(context);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResidentBottomTab()));
      print('Hello Tourist !!');
    
  }

  visitor() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var phone = prefs.getString('phone');
    String pass = prefs.getString("pass");
    await userProvider.login(context, phone, pass);
    await serviceProvider.getVisitorAdsList(context);
    await serviceProvider.getVisitorVideosList(context);
    bool type = prefs.getBool('type');
    print("Shared ******************visitor*****************************");
    if (alive) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VisitorHome()));
      print('Hello Tourist !!');
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    alive = false;
    super.dispose();
  }
```

login method

```
Future<VisitorLoginModel> login(BuildContext context, phone, pass) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      'phone': phone,
      'password': pass,
      'token': '123',
      'serial_number': '123',
      'lang': 'en',
      'os': 'android',
    };

    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    print('Starting request');
    http.Response response = await http.post(Environment.userLogin,
        body: json.encode(body), headers: Environment.requestHeader);
    print('Completed request');
    print('user SignUp response : ${response.body}');
    //print(body.toString());
    Map<String, dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
    var results;
    if (res['status'] == 1) {
      // login successful
      _visitorLoginModel = parseVisitorLogin(response.body);
      Provider.of<LoginVisitorUserProvider>(context, listen: false).userData =
          visitorLoginModel;
      Provider.of<LoginVisitorUserProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .sessionToken = visitorLoginModel.data.token;
      headers = Provider.of<LoginVisitorUserProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .httpHeader;
      // print('token');
      print('this is session token' +
          Provider.of<LoginVisitorUserProvider>(context, listen: false)
              .sessionToken);
    } else {
      // login failed;
      results =
          FailedRequest(code: 401, message: res['massage'], status: false);
    }
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return visitorLoginModel;
  }
```

So has anyone an idea to solve this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method call `await userProvider.login(context, phone, pass);` is being done on a non initialized variable. `UserProvider userProvider;` has been declared but not initialized

Comment: this is right , kindly can you mention how ho use it in main ?

Comment: @MariamYounes Please refer the answer that i attached now.You have to initialize it in initState

Comment: i put it in question , kindly check it

Comment: but still don't know how to use the shared preference method on main

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the `userProvider` is being declared but not initialized and the same goes for `serviceProvider`

In Flutter any uninitialized variable will implicitly assigned with null
So, at the line `await userProvider.login(context, phone, pass);` where you call `login` method in which userProvider is not only initialized

To Solve the issue do the following,
In initState,

```
userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
```